# How to config Amazon Route53 working without www in sub-domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

**edit:** Amazon now supports this. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/12/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3.html

I have my domain config in Route53 at Amazon AWS

exec ping command in my domain without www

```
$ ping mydomain.com.br
ping: cannot resolve domain.com.br: Unknown host
```

exec ping command in my domain with www

```
$ ping www.domain.com.br
PING s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com (177.72.245.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 177.72.245.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=244 time=25.027 ms
64 bytes from 177.72.245.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=25.238 ms
64 bytes from 177.72.245.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=244 time=25.024 ms
```

Route 53 -> Create Record Set -> Name: [   ].domain.com.br
Set CNAME value: www.domain.com.br

**DISPLAY ERROR**

> "RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name mydomin.com is not permitted at
>   apex in zone mydomin.com"

Comment: Hi, please note that answers should be provided in the Answers section below, NOT as edits to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a CNAME for the root-level domain, it violates the RFCs and can cause a number of problems. Unfortunately, Amazon doesn't have a workaround for S3-hosted websites.

**edit:** Amazon now supports this. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/12/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3.html

There are services like [WWWizer](http://wwwizer.com/) that you can use to redirect to the WWW, but they're not a perfect solution.

Comment: You CAN use CNAME's with root-level domains it does not violate RFC. The problem is that CNAME can not co-exist with other records e.g. MX. 

From RFC1034...... If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Comment: @JamesPark-Watt http://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp "The problem is the DNS RFC (RFC1033) requires the "zone apex" (sometimes called the "root domain" or "naked domain") to be an "A Record," not a CNAME."

Comment: Perfect -> [link](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/12/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3.html) Root Domain Website Hosting for Amazon S3

Comment: [Apex CNAMEs are not legal.](http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830#613830) It's been explicitly spelled out in [RFC2181](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-10.1) for awhile now.

Answer (score 5):

Create a resource record set (Type A - IPv4 address) that "has the same name as the hosted zone by leaving the Name field blank".

[image: Amazon Route 53 - Edit Record Set]

This is the warning Route 53 gives when trying to add the name "@", which I was custom too using for Bind nameservers. So don't use '@', use an empty name ''.

Comment: And now using the `@` works for A record to get a naked domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to point your root domain ***mydomain.com.br*** to service from AWS:

- create a record of type ***A - IPv4 Address***.
- then select ***Yes*** for Alias.
- ***Alias Target*** will list autocomplete for your AWS resources.