# How do I map root domain to external subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, codeigniter

I'm trying to map somedomain.com to here.anotherdomain.com. I can do any sub domains of the original using a CNAME but the root domain ( somedomain.com ) needs an A record. This is currently set to the ip address of the server ( anotherdomain.com ).

My question is, do I add a CNAME record of somedomain.com to point to here.anotherdomain.com on the server DNS zones?

```
NAMESERVER RECORDS
A somedomain.com 123.123.123.123
CNAME www here.anotherdomain.com

SERVER RECORDS
CNAME somedomain.com here.anotherdomain.com
```

The nameservers are at codeigniter and the server is cPanel.

Thanks for any help

Joe

Answer (score 1):

The DNS spec, `RFC 1035`, does not for the 'naked domain' (domain.com) to have `CNAME`'s. More technically, it states that a `CNAME` must be alone, so you can't have both `CNAME`'s and `NS`'s (and other records required for a domain to work).

Cloudflare went ahead and tried to handle this on their end, by allowing a `CNAME` as the root record, whereafter they will resolve it and present an `A` record to the end-user. You can use Cloudflare for their DNS service only, if you so wish - so that's always an option.

Source: http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/

Comment: I do love cloudflare! Great resource thanks for sharing!

Comment: It should be noted that what Cloudflare is doing is *not* a CNAME record as defined by the DNS standards. [It's a custom behavior that borrows the name of the record.](http://serverfault.com/a/613830/152073)

Answer (score 1):

Just put both somedomain.com and here.anotherdomain.com to the same ip address, create a vhost for here.anotherdomain.com and no vhost for your somedomain.com

or

put both in the same vhost enter somedomain.com and here.somedomain.com then make a rewright to your apache to your default domain here.anotherdomain.com.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. So am I write in thinking with the CNAMES in place, doing it this way will mask the domain?

Comment: @jhodgson4 No, you can't do it with a CNAME because it is a violation of standards. The best you can do (barring implementation specific behavior such as Cloudflare's) is to point the apex at a webserver that redirects them to the proper site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled, because somedomain.com doesn't need a A record. See for example the records for `fdn.fr` and `www.fdn.fr`. If your DNS provder require a A record for somedomain.com, you should put a HTTP redirect or something like that behind.

Yes you should add a CNAME record. If you really want users to connect to here.anotherdomain.com you should consider redirection mechanism at higher protocol level (e.g. HTTP 301 redirect)

Comment: You cannot CNAME the apex of a domain if the implementation is standards compliant. (ignoring Cloudflare, because what they do isn't a real CNAME)