# Forward the root domain to the www subdomain using DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding

I have `www.mydomain.com` pointed at an Azure Website.

```
www.mydomain.com --- CNAME --- mydomain.azurewebsites.net
```

When I visit `www.mydomain.com`, everything works fine. This is good.

Problem is, `mydomain.com` doesn't work. Azure only allows the www subdomain.

In some nameservers, I use a FWD Record to forward the root to the www, and this works fine. My current name server (zoneedit.com) does not have this FWD Record.

**Is there a DNS Record that we can use to forward the root domain to the www subdomain?**

Comment: ZoneEdit has a "WebForward" which will do this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Perfect. We used `@ | StealthForward | http://www.example.com`

Comment: That's great. It essentially does what I described (points to a real IP, that is a web server that just redirects with an HTTP 300-series to www.domain.com).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a well-known shortcoming of the DNS protocol. There is no record type defined within the DNS standards that will allow you to alias the apex of a domain. Many people assume that `CNAME` records can be used to accomplish this but [there are technical reasons why they cannot](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-of-a-domain).

Many DNS providers implement custom (read: fake) DNS record types to try and address this shortcoming. Behind the scenes, these fake records implement custom behavior in that company's software using a combination of synthesized `A` records and webserver redirection to accomplish your desired goal. `FWD` is one of these, much like the `WebForward` that Michael directed you to in the comments.

Comment: Looks like `ALIAS` is another one of these "fake" record types - from a quick Google it's offered by [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record/), [Gandi](https://docs.gandi.net/en/domain_names/faq/record_types/alias_record.html), [ClouDNS](https://www.cloudns.net/wiki/article/18/) and [dnsimple](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/)

Answer (score 13):

Summary: In short, you can't have the record you want, and your DNS host is doing things The Right Way.

Explanation: It is a violation of the DNS standadards to have a CNAME (alias record / forward record) at zone apex (the empty name at the front of the zone).

The reason for this is a CNAME record cannot have the name portion conflict with any record except a DNSSec record. In a typical zone, a CNAME record at zone apex would collide with at least the SOA and NS records (and likely several others). While some DNS servers will allow this, it is a Bad Thing, and can cause hard to diagnose failures (not to mention will not work if you move hosting of the zone to a standards-compliant DNS server, such as anything BIND-based).

Either have A records at zone apex (they can be a simple web server that just throws an HTTP 302 to www). If you can get static IP numbers for your Azure server instances, put an A record for each at the apex of your zone, and create a single CNAME record called "www" that points to the apex record.

As an example :

```
 

$ORIGIN example.com.

@    IN  SOA   ns1.example.com.  admin@example.com. (
                                 101 ;
                                 172800 ;
                                 900 ;
                                 1209600 ;
                                 3600 ; )
@    IN  NS    ns1.example.com.
@    IN  NS    ns2.example.com.
@    IN  A     123.234.1.123
@    IN  A     123.234.1.124
@    IN  A     123.234.1.125
ns1  IN  A     123.234.1.126
ns2  IN  A     123.234.1.127
www  IN  CNAME example.com.
```

Comment: IMO: It's not worth it to endlessly reiterate why CNAME apexes don't work. If the user asks why they don't work, we have a [canonical answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-of-a-domain) for that with RFC references. (full disclosure: I wrote it) If they don't ask about it, it's best to stick with answering the question as phrased.

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked for a canonical answer. I'll keep in mind that for next time.

Answer (score 4):

Some protocols have standards for DNS record types, other than A records, for finding the service.  SMTP with it's associated MX records is a good example of this.  There are no defined DNS record types for HTTP.  It's likely that your prior DNS/registrar provider had either an HTTP redirect or reverse proxy service.

In order to accomplish your goal you'll need to setup a webserver (virtual host) to do an HTTP 301 or 302 redirect from one hostname to the other, setup a reverse HTTP proxy, setup independent virtual hosts, or use virtual host aliases so the same webserver instance will respond to both A names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer specific to Azure you need to create another CNAME record pointing to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net like this

```
www.mydomain.com --- CNAME --- awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DNS provider, there is an option to do CNAME flattening (https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/cname-flattening/)

However, note that this feature is not available (yet) in all DNS providers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/551443)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).