# Need help for configuring a dns server

Tags: linux, nameserver, reverse-dns, dns-zone

I want to run a dns server to have my own nameservers :
ns1.radicalteam.ir and ns2.radicalteam.ir
I have a VPS and installed Centos 6.5 on it, and radicalteam.ir and soulati.ir domains
I've set soulati.ir nameservers to ns1.radicalteam.ir and ns2.radicalteam.ir
I can reach radicaalteam.ir but soulati.ir is unreachable . What is the problem ??
This is my configuration in bind :
/etc/named.conf :

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 185.94.97.188;127.0.0.1; };
    allow-query     { any; };
    Allow-transfer {"none";};
    Allow-recursion {"none";};
    Recursion no;
};

zone "server.radicalteam.ir" {
type master;
file "/var/named/server.radicalteam.ir.zone";
};

zone "radicalteam.ir" {
type master;
file "/var/named/radicalteam.ir.zone";
};
```

/var/named/server.radicalteam.ir.zone :

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN  SOA ns1.radicalteam.ir. admin.radicalteam.ir. (
                                        1       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum

server.radicalteam.ir. IN  NS   ns1.radicalteam.ir.
server.radicalteam.ir. IN  NS   ns2.radicalteam.ir.
server.radicalteam.ir. IN  A    185.94.97.188
server.radicalteam.ir. IN  MX   0 server.radicalteam.ir.
```

/var/named/radicalteam.ir.zone :

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN  SOA ns1.radicalteam.ir. server.radicalteam.ir. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum

radicalteam.ir. IN  NS      ns1.radicalteam.ir.
radicalteam.ir. IN  NS      ns2.radicalteam.ir.
radicalteam.ir. IN  A       185.94.97.188
ns1     IN  A   185.94.97.188
ns2     IN  A   185.94.97.188
radicalteam.ir. IN  MX  0  radicalteam.ir.
www         IN  CNAME   radicalteam.ir.
```

nslookup -debug radicalteam.ir

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    radicalteam.ir, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  radicalteam.ir
    internet address = 185.94.97.188
    ttl = 86400
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  radicalteam.ir
    nameserver = ns2.radicalteam.ir.
    ttl = 1290
    ->  radicalteam.ir
    nameserver = ns1.radicalteam.ir.
    ttl = 1290
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
    ->  ns1.radicalteam.ir
    internet address = 185.94.97.188
    ttl = 1290
    ->  ns2.radicalteam.ir
    internet address = 185.94.97.188
    ttl = 56785
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   radicalteam.ir
Address: 185.94.97.188
```

ping soulati.ir :

```
ping: unknown host soulati.ir
```

nslookup soulati.ir :

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find soulati.ir: SERVFAIL
```

nslookup -debug soulati.ir

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    soulati.ir, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find soulati.ir: SERVFAIL
```

Comment: are you sure it is a DNS problem and not something wrong with the webserver?  Try `ping` or `nslookup` with your hostnames and see if that works first.

Comment: "soulati.ir is unreachable": can you elaborate on this? what test, exactly, have you performed and which output did it  generated?

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli Debug info added to the post

Comment: @chicks Debug info added to the post

Comment: "soulati.ir is unreachable": you're unable to " resolve" at DNS level. Please provide  details about related DNS configuration, as your  question is lacking any kind of detail about "soulati.ir" domain/zone configuration.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli I've set soulati.ir nameservers to ns1.radicalteam.ir and ns2.radicalteam.ir. Do I need additional configuration for soulati.ir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ns1.radicalteam.ir` and `ns2.radicalteam.ir` resolve to  the same address, `185.94.97.188` which is a bad idea in itself if these are supposed to be your "nameserver**s**".

As for `soulati.ir` (delegated to the above "nameserver**s**"), `185.94.97.188` responds with status `REFUSED`, presumably because you have no such zone configured. (If the config included in the question is the complete configuration that confirms this.)

Comment: Should I configure different zone for every domain that I want to host ?

Comment: You need to explicitly configure each domain your name server is authoritative for, but when each domain is configured identically, they can [share  a single zone file](http://serverfault.com/a/669830/37681)

Comment: You said its bad idea to have same ip for both nameservers , you mean I have to start another vps for ns2.radicaltem.i ? or what ? I'm totally noob in this field

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/710108 and http://serverfault.com/q/23744 might clarify that