# Default A record for custom nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, domain-parking

I have quite a few domains parked that are currently not in use, so I am looking into a dead simple way to maintain them and display a custom parking-page. I do not want to update every single one the DNS-records on all of the domains separately – instead I want the ability to just have default nameservers / NS-records for all the domains and to have "the rest handle itself".

What I am looking for is setting up a custom nameserver (ie. `ns.example.com`) which I can apply for each domains; what I want to happen then is that all domains with that nameserver automatically gets an A-record which I can point to the server of my liking.

On that "target"-server I can then just check the URL and display an appropriate parking-page (if needed, or just serve a default one).

I've begun reading up on BIND setting up a custom nameserver – is this the way to go? If so, anything special I should look into to speed up the time to deployment?

Or even better, are there any "ready to use"-solutions that would fit my needs? (Preferably free, but I'm more than willing to pay for good systems).

Comment: You can't achieve *"I do not want to update all the DNS-records on all of the domains separate"* when you are going to *"set up a custom nameserver which I can apply for each domains"*. Setting up your own name-server requires at least one update for each domain because you'll need update the NS records for those domains... - See the DNS topic [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/1987/37681)  regarding the wisdom of running your own and a only single name server and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/669830/37681) on how to use use a single template for identically configured domains.

Comment: My bad; you are correct. I should have frased it differently; "currently I do say 'I do not want to update all the DNS-records'"; I am fully prepared to set my NS-records. This is easier however as most registrars offer the ability to set default nameservers for all registered domains.

Answer (score 0):

This should be moved to unix.se ... but to do this is fairly easy. I run my own DNS servers so I buy a domain, set its DNS servers to ns1.mydomain and ns2.mydomain, and run a few shell scripts on my primary and secondary servers to set up zone files, an apache vhost, and mail service.

If you don't feel like duct taping your own solution together like I did, there are service management consoles that you can use that would do all of this, and allow creation of sub-management, etc for resellers and so on.  If this is of interest to you, I'd recommend looking at ISPConfig - https://www.ispconfig.org