# CNAME interfering with MX record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, cname-record, dns-hosting

I have got a free domain at [Freenom](http://freenom.com), which I use to host my website, and to receive email.

About a month ago, I used an A record to point `[Blank]` and `www` to the A record of my webhosting.
I also had a MX record to my email provider, [Zoho mail](http://zoho.com/mail).

Now that I changed webhosting, I only have a CNAME to point my domain to.
Since I changed it, I don't receive mail anymore, altough I can still send mail.
When I remove my CNAME, my mail starts working again.
Is there any way to use both my email, and the CNAME record?

For the people who think this is a duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain):
My problem is that the MX and the CNAME records interfere, not about CNAME not working, or whether I should or shouldn't use a CNAME for my site root

Comment: I don't think so, I explained why

Answer (score 4):

The CNAME will override your MX record.

I assume you have a CNAME on the root of your domain, i.e. example.com without any 'www' in front. If this is true and you also have the CNAME set on the same address then the CNAME is stopping your mail getting delivered.

This can be avoided my setting the CNAME on "www" only and then using a url redirect to send visitors from http://yourdomain.com to http://www.yourdomain.com this way you can still use an MX record on yourdomain.com without losing mail.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I found another way (see my own answer)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve my problem, turns out I could also get the A record for my site (silly me), so now my problem is fixed.
I now use:

```
[blank]  A   ip  
 www     A   ip

[blank]  MX  mail.zoho.com
```