# CNAME one domain to another

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have created a CNAME for www.example.com  to   example.org

I would like to create a CNAME for   example.com  to  example.org

Or, do I not need to do that?

Our former email domain rather than pointing to an IP address now needs to point to a cloud domain.

Comment: If you want to receive any email to any address within example.com, then you don't want to use a CNAME as the apex record.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/613829/126632

Answer (score 0):

Creating cname for root domain is not permitted by rfc.

Comment: Please extend your answer by providing an explanation of what is wrong, how it can be resolved and probably link the RFC your are referring to.

Comment: While the answer could have been more detailed, it's also correct, and I don't think that this is -2 worthy for a completely new user.