# Name server NS records missing

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I'm trying to setup dns on the cheap and running into some problems.

- I have a domain registered with crazydomains.com.au
- I have a vps served by Iniz.com
- I have setup (i think) dns settings with namecheap.com

Checking the information at intodns.com reveals a bunch of errors.

In the Parent section, I have the following blue warnings.

> Domain NS Records:
>
> Nameserver records returned by the parent servers are:
>
> dns1.registrar-servers.com.   ['216.87.155.33'] (NO GLUE)
> [TTL=86400]  dns2.registrar-servers.com.   ['216.87.152.33'] (NO GLUE)
> [TTL=86400]
>
> a0.org.afilias-nst.info was kind enough to give us that information.

I think the warning relates to the lack of glue, but I'm not sure.

> DNS Parent sent Glue
>
> The parent nameserver a0.org.afilias-nst.info is not sending out GLUE
> for every nameservers listed, meaning he is sending out your
> nameservers host names without sending the A records of those
> nameservers. It's ok but you have to know that this will require an
> extra A lookup that can delay a little the connections to your site.
> This happens a lot if you have nameservers on different TLD
> (domain.com for example with nameserver ns.domain.org.)

more glue issues, it seems.

In the NS section I have the following warnings
blue:

> NS records from your nameservers
>
> NS records got from your nameservers listed at the parent NS are:
> Oups! I could not get any nameservers from your nameservers (the ones
> listed at the parent server). Please verify that they are not lame
> nameservers and are configured properly.

red:

> Mismatched NS records
>
> WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.

> DNS servers responded
>
> ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
> The ones that did not respond are:
> 216.87.155.33 216.87.152.33

> Multiple Nameservers
>
> ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 >section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 >nameservers is also ok by me.
>
> Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers
>
> You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are
> missing, so here it is again:
>
> dns1.registrar-servers.com.  dns2.registrar-servers.com.

I also have SOA, MX and WWW A record problems, but I think they are secondary to the above.

My dns settings in crazydomains:
[image: crazy domains ns setup]

My dns settings in namecheap:
[image] Ignore error, it's just the IP number.  However it shows I have set up the NS records at the name server.

/etc/resolv/conf from the vps:

> nameserver 216.87.152.33 
> nameserver 216.87.155.33 
> ~

How do I fix my name server issue?  If there's any other information that would be useful, just let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a CNAME record for your domain apex.

[image: CNAME on domain apex]

Remember that the CNAME overrides all other records for a given name, and that means the NS records in particular cease to have effect.

Namecheap really should have rejected the attempt to create this record, but since they didn't, you will have to remove it yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for the help.  I thought cname records were just a way of aliasing 'www.foo.com' to point to 'foo.com'. Making this change doesn't alter the contents of the intodns report, however.  Is that due to a  propagation thing, or do I have more issues to fix?

Comment: You need to wait for the TTL to expire. I have no idea what Namecheap uses for a TTL when it is set to "Automatic".

Comment: I've fixed the cname issue (and TTL looks like 86400 seconds, according to [dnsstuff.com](http://www.dnsstuff.com)).  This hasn't worked as I'm still getting the same results from intodns.  Is it because I don't have any SOA records?

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  Got it sorted.  I was not using namecheap's free dns servers - must've read the wrong help article.  Name server should've been freedns1.registrar-servers.com.  As I have also removed the incorrect cname record,  yours is the tick.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using namecheap dns hosting then you need to update namecheap name server in domain control panel (crazydomains.com.au) and update A records (vps server IP) .