# CNAME as different domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I've a query with regards to CNAME record, can I have a CNAME as different domain name? Ex. I've a website example.com, can I create a CNAME with example.net? So, irrelevant of what end user types (either example.com or example.net) they should always reach example.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two issues collide here.  The first is can a CNAME point to a different domain, to which the answer is yes, that is perfectly acceptable.

The second, though, is that *in the case of your example, you cannot use a CNAME at all*, because [you cannot use a CNAME at the apex (aka root) of a domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain).  `foo.example.net` can be a CNAME; `example.net` cannot.

Comment: This may be dangerous to suggest to inexperienced admins, but there are `ALIAS` and `ANAME` records which can be attached to the root domain and provide *similar* behavior to a `CNAME`. With that said, *make sure you know what you are doing* before deploying these types of records.

Comment: @Brennen It also needs to be mentioned that `ALIAS` and `ANAME` are *not* record types defined by the standards. They are custom behavior in certain server implementations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to redirect example.net web site visitors to example.com , that's what you should do. Point example.net A DNS record to example.com's IP address. After that, you have a couple of options;

-Create a new website on your host that accepts example.net visitors and redirect them using HTML/Javascript in your index page , or using your server's redirection capabilities.

-On your single website, check to see if visitors' URL matches example.net and redirect them to example.com using Javascript in your index page.

Pick one.

Comment: Or you could just use a ServerAlias and not have to worry about all the coding and redirects.

Comment: Does it change the URL tho? If it's something like "Host headers" in IIS, URL will stay "example.net" .