# Implications of hosting CNAMES and A records on separate name servers

Tags: domain-name-system

We host several websites but in most cases the client hosts their own DNS and mail separately.

I want to set up a system where we will create a subdomain on our domain for each client site which will act as the clients A record, so we can control the IP.

For example on the clients name server for domain clientwebsite.com set up:

```
@    CNAME clientwebsite.sharedhostingenv.com
www  CNAME clientwebsite.sharedhostingevn.com
```

And on our name servers create the subdomain on sharedhostingenv.com:

```
clientwebsite IN A 222.33.55.66
```

Will the fact that the client no longer hosts their own A record have any effect on any other records they have? Will this adversely affect any MX records that the client hosts?

edit:
Thank you for the feedback!!! I can't comment, but cheers.

Comment: Regarding your edit: it seems you have created two different profiles, because you should always be able to comment on your own questions. See [this page](http://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts) to get that resolved.

Comment: In general when you want to say "thank you," [vote up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. - See [this FAQ page](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) with regards to the etiquette on ServerFault and related sites. - For an Answer to a Question you yourself asked then you additionally have the option to accept it as the correct answer... - Of course you can also completely disagree with an answer as well and vote down ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Don't do this**:

```
@    CNAME clientwebsite.sharedhostingenv.com
```

That will break all other resource records for your clients domain. See [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) for a long explanation.

Second when using [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)'s in DNS zones, do not omit the trailing <kbd>.</kbd> dot.
In DNS shorthand an entry such as `clientwebsite.sharedhostingevn.com` in your client's `example.com.` DNS zone effectively becomes: `clientwebsite.sharedhostingevn.com.example.com.`