# What's the diference between ANAME and A?

Tags: domain-name-system, aname-record

The new *revolution of DNS records* they say but, what's the difference between the current A (AAAA) records and ANAME ones?

[This are ANAME records](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/anamerecords/)

Comment: It's a fake DNS record which exists solely so that some developers can avoid putting `www` in their URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't understand the difference between an `A` record and a `CNAME` record, don't worry about it and continue using `A(AAA)` records. You aren't missing out on anything. There's nothing terribly revolutionary about them, it's mostly marketing hype.

`ANAME` is a custom record type which emulates the behavior of a `CNAME` record, but can be used at the apex of the domain. This is desirable for some because [CNAME records cannot be used at the apex of a domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain). It doesn't break the existing standards because the server software "clones" the target instead of using an actual `CNAME`.

It must be emphasized that `ANAME` (and similar features advertised by other companies, such as [`ALIAS`](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/)) are not part of the DNS standards. As such, do not expect the aliasing to be intact if you switch DNS hosting companies.

Comment: Alright, just another way to rip-off people, amazing..

Comment: @Alex uh, what?

Comment: @hobbs I believe the OP got the impression from reading the linked marketing material that these were superior to `A(AAA)` records. That or it was a reaction to perceived vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 5):

Just to spell out more clearly what the previous answer says: the difference between A/AAAA and ANAME is that A and AAAA are DNS record types, while ANAME is a *service* offered by some DNS hosting providers. They implement that service by creating actual DNS records (A, AAAA and others) on the fly. It can be a convenient service, but it doesn't mean that you can find ANAME anywhere in [the official list of DNS record types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-4).