# same entry for CNAME and sub-domain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record, srv-record

SRV Record:
_xmpp-server._tcp.meet.domain.com => target=server-name.domain.com (A Record)

CNAME:
meet.domain.com => target=server-name.domain.com (A record)

As you can see, the word "meet" already a "sub-domain" under domain.com (for the SRV records in meet.domain.com). Can the same word "meet" also be a CNAME under the zone "domain.com" ?

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see, the word "meet" already a "sub-domain" under domain.com (for the SRV records in meet.domain.com).

Yes, but note that it is not necessarily defined as its own zone with its own NS and SOA records.

> Can the same word "meet" also be a CNAME under the zone "domain.com" ?

This should work as long as you don't want to create any other records for the name *meet.domain.com* (since if a name has a CNAME record it can't have any other records associated with it).

Comment: _Yes, but note that it is not necessarily defined as its own zone with its own NS and SOA records_ ::


This is not the case for us here. A new DNS zone is going to be created for meet.domain.com

Comment: _This should work as long as you don't want to create any other records for the name meet.domain.com (since if a name has a CNAME record it can't have any other records associated with it)_ ::

"should" ? This is in production and I am looking to hear from someone who has tried something similar and confirm it is working.

Comment: *A new DNS zone is going to be created for meet.domain.com* Well, you can't have the apex of your zone be a CNAME.  There are lots of posts here that explain this better than I can.  But my main point was the fact that the existence of SRV `a.b.c.com` does not preclude the existence of CNAME `b.c.com`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But why can't the apex of zone be not a CNAME? In my case the CNAME "meet" is hosted under example.com and the subdomain of "meet" is going to have its own SOA etc. I don't quite understand why would this be a problem.

Comment: [Apex CNAMEs are illegal per RFC 2181.](http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) If you create a new zone, that zone will have mandatory `NS` and `SOA` records at the apex. A `CNAME` record cannot coexist with the majority of record types.

Comment: @AndrewB : But the CNAME for "meet" will exist in "example.com" zone and the meet.example.com will have its own SOA. Am I completely wrong with this understanding? If not, why should CNAME record in top domain affect the sub-domain?

Comment: If `meet` is a CNAME in `example.com` then it can't also be a subdomain of `example.com`.  When a resolver queries `example.com` name servers for `meet.example.com` it can receive *either* a referral for the `meet.example.com` servers *or* a response that `meet` is a CNAME.

Comment: Thanks @GrishaLevit : Will the problem go away if "meet" was a A Record instead of CNAME?

Comment: Yep, an A record is fine.