# Add A, AAAA, and CNAME record for google app engine project in google cloud platform

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, a-record, google-app-engine

I am adding a new google app engine project and trying to map it to a subdomain.

I have already created a CNAME which maps `newmachine.mycompany.com` to `newproject.appsport.com`, and I am able to use it in 'App Engine' -> 'Settings' ->'Custom domains'.

But once the mapping is finsihed, the same screen shows the following messages:

```
Configure resource records on your domain registrar
Have your domain registrar add the following resource records for mycompany.com:
Type    Data    Alias
A   215.234.32.21   
A   215.234.34.21   
A   215.234.36.21   
A   215.234.38.21   
AAAA    1997:2340:4801:32::15   
AAAA    1997:2340:4801:34::15   
AAAA    1997:2340:4801:36::15   
AAAA    1997:2340:4801:38::15   
CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com    newmachine
```

I haven't seen this message before. As a matter of face, no such A and AAAA were created for other existing GAE projects.

My questions are:

1. What is the implication of NOT adding these records to my DNS server?
2. What purpose do they serve? Is it simply to provide a reverse IP lookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list seems to be incomplete and confusing, but I guess it means:

```
@           IN A     215.234.32.21   
@           IN A     215.234.34.21   
@           IN A     215.234.36.21   
@           IN A     215.234.38.21   
@           IN AAAA  1997:2340:4801:32::15   
@           IN AAAA  1997:2340:4801:34::15   
@           IN AAAA  1997:2340:4801:36::15   
@           IN AAAA  1997:2340:4801:38::15   
newmachine  IN CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

That's because `@ IN CNAME` wouldn't make any sense, as an alias defined by `CNAME` should not have any other type records, including mentioned `A` / `AAAA`, but also `MX` breaking email and `NS` & `SOA` breaking the DNS itself; see the [canonical question about `CNAME`s at the apices of zones](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain).

Now, because you already have `newmacine CNAME` and don't want to move whole `example.com` to Google App Engine, there shouldn't be any reasonable purpose for the other records.

Comment: Indeed the message is very strange.