# App Engine > Subdomain > Add A, AAAA and CNAME record

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to add a subdomain `subdomain.domain.com` to App Engine.

It asks to add the following DNS records

[image]

But it's impossible to add a A record and a CNAME record with the same name `subdomain.domain.com` because it causes a conflict.

I saw in this thread that the CNAME name that Google asks to add doesn't seem to make sense [Add A, AAAA, and CNAME record for google app engine project in google cloud platform](https://serverfault.com/questions/849637/add-a-aaaa-and-cname-record-for-google-app-engine-project-in-google-cloud-plat)

But in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?csw=1#dns_update) that is what they're asking to do:

```
Record name:
In A or AAAA records, enter @
In CNAME records, enter a third-level domain name. For example, enter www to map the www.example.com subdomain.
```

How can I add the CNAME and A records that they ask if they both have the same name?

Comment: The CNAME appears to be for `tagman.example.com`; the rest are for `example.com`. They don't conflict.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you for the comment. I set the A and the AAAA records for the subdomain which i'm trying to add to App Engine. I though of setting A records on the naked domain instead, but I have my hosting IP in the A records and in their documentation they mention that I should use either their IPs for A records or my hosting IP and not mix them.

Comment: You only need to add the `CNAME` if you only want to add the subdomain. No need to add  `A` and `AAAA` records. You can verify by using the [dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) tool. The previous comment is correct.