# Redirect apex domain to www with Route53 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup redirect from the apex domain `example.com` to `www.example.com` with route53, cloudfront and s3.

I've seen many tutorials online and discussions here on the topic, but nothing has worked for me yet. And it's not clear e**xactly what records to create** in route53.

Currently I have,

```
ALIAS    A    example.com    www.example.com

ALIAS    A    www.example.com    abcdefg.cloudfront.net
```

As recommended in this setup [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwZ3wNaM69s) and many others.

This didn't work so I also tried to add a `.htaccess` with the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which didn't work either.

Lots of people also suggest using a CNAME record, however it seems quite obvious to me that this doesn't work and mentioned in this answer [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two concepts are being mixed.  An `ALIAS` record in the DNS just affects how `example.com` resolves to an IP address.  What you have done has exactly the same effect as

```
ALIAS    A    example.com        abcdefg.cloudfront.net
ALIAS    A    www.example.com    abcdefg.cloudfront.net
```

It won't actually redirect a web browser.  Redirection would be caused by the web server.

You're on the right track with the `.htaccess` file, but typically only Apache web servers process the rules in a `.htaccess` file.  S3 is not an Apache web server, and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095818/amazon-s3-and-htaccess) suggests that rules in `.htaccess` files on S3 are not processed.

If it were processed, the rules in your question are redirecting visitors *from* `www.example.com` *to* `example.com`, and your question suggests you want to do the opposite.  So move the `www.` from the `RewriteCond` to the `RewriteRule` line.  Again, if S3 is not looking at the rules in `.htaccess`, then whatever you put there won't result in the redirect you're aiming for.

You should probably investigate other methods of redirecting which don't use `.htaccess`, such as the [method described here](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-https-amazon-cloudfront/#configuring-the-amazon-s3-static-site-with-redirect).  Or if you need more comprehensive rule processing, use a more fully-featured HTTP server instead of S3.

Comment: still not working. Gave it a few days too.

Comment: Are you sure Cloudfront/S3 is processing the `.htaccess` file?  If you are sure this is happening (e.g. by redirecting *all* requests) then please show your revised `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I created an invalidation for the file to clear the cache. here's the file.
```RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]```
Thanks

Comment: I wasn't referring to caching.  S3 is not an Apache web server, so the question is whether your `.htaccess` file even gets processed or if it is completely ignored.  At least previously it was not processed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095818/amazon-s3-and-htaccess).

Comment: I see yep, it is being processed. I couldn't see any solutions from the link that applied to me. I tried the build in s3 redirect, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show the `.htaccess` file that you tested which did successfully do something?

Comment: It's the same as the comment above (Aug 3rd @ 11:10). It is reachable via the link, `example.com/.htaccess` and downloads that file. However, the url is never redirected and stays on the apex domain.

Comment: If you can download it, that suggests S3 is treating it as a regular file.  Your `.htaccess` rules should not be visible to the public.  Basically my suspicion is that S3 does not process *any* rules in a `.htaccess` file (see link in above comment) and so far there hasn't been any evidence to the contrary.  If the `.htaccess` file is not being processed, then it will be impossible to do such a redirect using `RewriteRule`.  You'd need to either give up on the redirect; see if CloudFront itself offers redirection; or move to a proper web server.

Comment: I added a new link in the answer which shows an approach not using `.htaccess`.