# What happens if i have both A record and CNAME record on my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Let's suppose i have a domain which DNS contains 2 records:

- a "A" record which contains an IP Address
- a "CNAME" record which contains another domain (alias). Let's suppose this domain contains an IP to a second IP Address

My question is: Which one of the 2 IP Addresses will be answered if i ask a DNS resolution of my domain ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Comment: Although primarily concern with the apex the point is that standards don’t allow a CnAME to coexist with other records

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a `CNAME` record and other records for the same name.
If the scenario in the question is that you would have a `CNAME` record and an `A` record side by side, that is not really a concern since it is not possible.

Comment: There is nothing in the DNS protocol it self that prevents an implementation of a DNS server from being configured with both `CNAME` and `A` records nor that would make it impossible for a server to respond with both of them. It may be true that any correct server will refuse (and that basically all do), but the question of *"what would happen in practice if ...?"* is still interesting. -- In practice, load balancing across servers with inconsistent configurations could in some ways result in the appearance of this situation even with all the servers being standard compliant.

Comment: @BCS I disagree with *there is nothing in the DNS protocol it self that prevents...* as it is clear in the spec that a name cannot have this combination of records. Of course the wire format can represent invalid things, including this, but the DNS protocol is more than just the wire format. As a (quick and dirty) comparison you can certainly write "slkdjfkldsj" using the English alphabet but that does not make it valid English.  **I really do like your point about how caching can introduce this type of inconsistency, with different zone data on different auth servers or also just over time.**

Comment: While I'll grant you are correct about it being *invalid* I was more pointing out that the question of "what would the result be of it happening anyway" it still relevant. As for *why* that's relevant; I refer you to the ever growing list of security issues that boil down to "they didn't implement it according to the spec". :0) Also, it's fun to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a server at IP address 111.111.111.111. You also have a domain called example.com. You can create an A record for example.com to point to 111.111.111.111.

The format that is used for a CNAME is **[name]** is an alias of **[target]**.

So if you create a CNAME name: www.example.com to a target: example.com then www.example.com will do a redirect call for example.com, which will resolve to the IP address of 111.111.111.111.

[image: CNAME resolves to A record]

So basically when you create a CNAME you do not set another IP address, so you will only have one (the original A record) IP address to resolve to.

Original source of image: https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-a-cname-record

Comment: No in fact i want to know what happens if cname is targeting another domain and if this other domain contains a « A » field with a 222.222.222.222 ip for example

Comment: If you try to add the same CNAME to a different host you will get an error message such as:  "An A, AAAA, or CNAME record with that host already exists. (Code: 81053)"