# How to enable HTTPS for my marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, php, ssl, cloudflare

I'm building a marketplace platform that enables many merchants to sell to their customers. At the moment I serve stores on my own domain like so `https://storeA.mydomain.com` or `https://storeB.mydomain.com` (I'm able to use the subdomain to distinguish which store is to be served). However, I'd like to enable my merchants to use their own domains on my platform whilst being able to secure the site over HTTPS, how can I achieve this automatically? In the past, I've tried CNAME to CNAME but this doesn't allow HTTPS.

EDIT: If you know of any intermediary services (that offer some sort of domain masking) that the merchants would be able to use that would be great!

Comment: Unless your company is a CA itself, or has close relationship with a CA so that you can request certificates for your customers on their behaves under strict restrictions (Cloudflare does that), you are not able to support HTTPS for custom domains not owned by you. The workaround is to ask your customers to request certificates on their own and share with you, but that's also a lengthy process. Whenever security is the biggest concern, automating the steps is almost impossible.

Comment: @LexLi I've seen Cloudflare's certificate feature, but it's very costly (being part of their Enterprise plan) and not an option for small software startups, unfortunately.

Comment: @LexLi: Have you ever heard of Let's Encrypt & Certbot?

Comment: @EsaJokinen I definitely know of that. That's still a manual process, as any customer must modify DNS on his/her side to assist (and different DNS providers require very different steps), which Cloudflare as DNS service provider can automate.

Comment: I did some digging and came across this possible solution using Caddy, but I haven't experimented with it yet. (https://www.indiehackers.com/post/generating-ssl-certs-on-demand-with-caddy-server-69ad07a3fb)

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to automate this with Let's Encrypt using Certbot, but I'm afraid there's no existing ready for use solution for this. Therefore, it requires some scripting, and you may need to hire someone, as you asked this question.

**I would suggest something like this** (examples are for the Apache 2.4 web server):

1. Create a catch-all configuration that points `http://*/.well-known/acme-challenge/` to the same directory with any domain and with the default virtual host for the rest. This is possible with a global [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) that could be placed in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/acme-challenge.conf`:

   ```
   <IfModule alias_module>
     Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Let your customers input their custom domains for validation and save the information somewhere, with a reference to the correct customer. A database would be ideal for that, wouldn't it. Possibly limit this to one custom hostname (& www) per customer.
3. Instruct your customers to point their domains to the correct IP address. In the case of a subdomain, a `CNAME` record will work, but [at the domain apex](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) you will need to provide instructions for an `A` record.

   Here, the examples simply assume every domain has both `example.com` and `www.example.com`, but you can modify this according to your requirements.
4. Do not launch [HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) immediately, but create a script launched with a *cronjob* or a *Systemd timer*. The script should first check whether the domains waiting for validation points to your server or not, and launch the ACME challenge only for domains that meets the condition. Otherwise, someone could abuse the feature and make your server perform unnecessary Let’s Encrypt validations.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   MYSERVERIP="192.0.2.123"

   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
     printf "\n%s\n\n" "Usage: $0 example.com" >&2
     exit 1
   fi

   host "$1" 2>&1 > /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     printf "\n%s\n\n" "The given domain is not a valid FQDN." >&2
     exit 1
   fi
   IPAPEX=$(dig "$1" +short | tail -n 1)
   IPWWW=$(dig "www.$1" +short | tail -n 1)

   if [ "$IPAPEX" = "$MYSERVERIP" ]; then
     if [ "$IPWWW" = "$MYSERVERIP" ]; then
       certbot certonly --quiet --webroot -w /var/www/letsencrypt -d $1 -d www.$1
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         printf "\n%s\n\n" "Certbot failed with HTTP-01 challenge." >&2
         exit 1
       fi
     else
       printf "\n%s\n\n" "Failed: www.$1 is not pointing to $MYSERVERIP." >&2
       exit 1
     fi
   else
     printf "\n%s\n\n" "Failed: $1 is not pointing to $MYSERVERIP." >&2
     exit 1
   fi
   ```
5. Once the validation is completed, the script may also add the configuration to the web server. You might use a [macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html), e.g. `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/custdomain-macro.conf`:

   ```
   <Macro CustomWebShopDomain $customer $domain>
       <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName $domain
           ServerAlias www.$domain
           Redirect permanent / https://$domain/
       </VirtualHost>
       <VirtualHost *:443>
           ServerName $domain
           SSLEngine on
           SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem
           SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem
           SSLVerifyClient None
           DocumentRoot /path/to/webshop/$customer
       </VirtualHost>
       <VirtualHost *:443>
           ServerName www.$domain
           SSLEngine on
           SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem
           SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem
           SSLVerifyClient None
           Redirect permanent / https://$domain/
       </VirtualHost>
   </Macro>
   ```

   In this case, adding a new customer domain would be simple:

   ```
   Use CustomWebShopDomain customerid example.com
   ```

   Your script might add this line to the configuration and then reload the Apache web server:

   ```
   printf "%s\n" "Use CustomWebShopDomain $2 $1" \
     >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/custdomain-use.conf
   systemctl reload apache2
   ```

**Be sure to clean out expired domains**

Certbot adds all the domains for automatic renewals. If those renewals start to fail, you don't want to keep those domains in the configuration forever. It's best to automate the removal, i.e.

1. Remove the Certbot configuration `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com`
2. Remove the `Use CustomWebShopDomain customerid example.com` line.