# What's the use case of SVCB (type 65 , service binding) RR

Tags: domain-name-system

I am getting lot of SVCB (type 65) queries from my clients. On further digging , i figure out that few clients (like apple iOS 14) uses this RR heavily.

sample query of SVCB (type 65) is as follows -

```
dig gsp85-ssl.ls.apple.com -t type65 @1.10.10.10

; <<>> DiG  <<>> gsp85-ssl.ls.apple.com -t type65 @1.10.10.10
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30904
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gsp85-ssl.ls.apple.com.        IN  TYPE65

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gsp85-ssl.ls.apple.com. 1823    IN  CNAME   gsp85-ssl.ls2-apple.com.akadns.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
akadns.net.     117 IN  SOA internal.akadns.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1619000353 90000 90000 90000 180

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 24 20:33:05 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 164
```

I have the following doubts -

i. Does type65 RR can be a replacement of CNAME , especially in cases as we can't have CNAME at the top level of the zone

ii. How i can instruct the browsers to ask for type65 queries instead of A or AAAA for my domain so that i have my abc.com directly over CDN

iii. which version of bind supports SVCB (type 65) RR

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SVCB`/`HTTPS` DNS records are currently being worked on (see https://github.com/MikeBishop/dns-alt-svc/blob/master/draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-https.md for the working document or https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-https-07.txt at IETF) but not yet finalised.

The strange ambiguous situation right now is that IANA already registered the codes for them (which is why they can already happen in the wild and be interoperable, through the RFC 3597 way of handling generic record types), even if the RFC is not yet ready/published, and some vendors (Apple and Cloudflare, see below) said they already implemented it and use it.

See https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-https-and-http-3-negotiation-with-dns/ for example for Cloudflare, which also gives an example why it is used. I recommend reading it, probably before the technical standard itself, except if you already master DNS and TLS.

The idea came out basically after/during TLS 1.3 (and encrypted clientHello/encrypted SNI needs), and HTTP/3 and QUIC. The document aims to solve multiple problems in fact, where part of them were already solved by `SRV` records that no browsers decided to implement back then.

As taken from the abstract:

> SVCB
> records allow a service to be provided from multiple alternative
> endpoints, each with associated parameters (such as transport
> protocol configuration and keys for encrypting the TLS ClientHello).
> They also enable aliasing of apex domains, which is not possible with
> CNAME.  The HTTPS RR is a variation of SVCB for HTTPS and HTTP
> origins.  By providing more information to the client before it
> attempts to establish a connection, these records offer potential
> benefits to both performance and privacy.

Now on your specific points:

> i. Does type65 RR can be a replacement of CNAME , especially in cases as we can't have CNAME at the top level of the zone

Yes, `SVCB/HTTPS` were designed to help handling the "CNAME at apex" case.
See "10.3.2.  Apex aliasing" in the draft:

```
   Consider a zone that is using CNAME aliasing:

   $ORIGIN aliased.example. ; A zone that is using a hosting service
   ; Subdomain aliased to a high-performance server pool
   www             7200 IN CNAME pool.svc.example.
   ; Apex domain on fixed IPs because CNAME is not allowed at the apex
   @                300 IN A     192.0.2.1
                        IN AAAA  2001:db8::1

   With HTTPS RRs, the owner of aliased.example could alias the apex by
   adding one additional record:

   @               7200 IN HTTPS 0 pool.svc.example.
```

> ii. How i can instruct the browsers to ask for type65 queries instead of A or AAAA for my domain so that i have my abc.com directly over CDN

You will have to wait for browsers to support it :-)

Have a look at the thread at https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/dnsop/eeP4H9fli712JPWnEMvDg1sLEfg/ ; there is support in iOS 14 and Safari it seems, in some experimental fashion.

The blog article at Cloudflare gives at the end two links to track status of feature in Firefox and Chrome:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/brZTXr6-2PU/m/g0g8wWwCAwAJ stating in April 2021: "Chrome will soon begin experimenting with querying HTTPS and INTEGRITY via Classic DNS (Do53) on platforms where Chrome regularly handles Do53 via its built-in resolver (Android, ChromeOS, and MacOS)."
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634793 : just showing that the feature right now depends on 5 other still open bugs that probably need to be closed first, without any timeframes

By the way, pleased don't obfuscate badly. Use `example.com` in documentation, see RFC2606

> iii. which version of bind supports SVCB (type 65) RR

None shipped yet.
This is tracked in https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/1132
It has been merged **6** days ago :-)
So maybe the next versions will ship it, based on what is in the ticket for the milestone:
"September 2021 (9.11.36, 9.11.36-S1, 9.16.21, 9.16.21-S1, 9.17.18)"

However, thanks to RFC 3597 you should be able to enter the records using the generic syntax, with `TYPE65` in the zonefile, and bind should serve it. You loose obviously syntax checks and other features (you can look at https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/merge_requests/5332/diffs to see exactly what "adding SVCB/HTTPS support to bind" means code-wise; see §4 in the IETF draft to see what specific support authoritative and recursive resolvers need to have for these records; it is a SHOULD so variations are accepted if good reasons, like no true full support yet in the software), but at least you can serve the records.

But remember, there is not just bind out there:

- PowerDNS has support already: https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/guides/svcb.html
- July version of nsd has support too: https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/news/2021/Jul/22/nsd-4.3.7-released/ with "New features are XoT which provides AXFR and IXFR over TLS, and DNS Cookies support and SVCB and HTTPS RR type support."
- Knot DNS also, at https://www.knot-dns.cz/2021-08-02-version-310.html with an August release and some support: "libs: support for parsing and dumping SVCB and HTTPS resource records"

So you can already experiment full support with other software.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick  for such a nice and detailed explanation.

Comment: Any insight into why browsers didn't implement SRV but they implemented SVCB? Also, any idea why HTTPS had to be an entirely new record type, rather than one type of SVCB record?

Comment: @MilindR "Any insight into why browsers didn't implement SRV but they implemented SVCB?" Claims of delaying display too much (more DNS queries) + lack of proper support by OS to fetch those new records + see other points at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records ; "Also, any idea why HTTPS had to be an entirely new record type, rather than one type of SVCB record?" Not required (SVCB is enough for all cases), but since HTTPS traffic will be 99.999% of use cases of SVCB, this simplify things (imagine the UI of a DNS provider...). See §9 of the draft.

Comment: @MilindR "didn't implement SRV but they implemented SVCB?" Things have changed a lot between the two, and DoH appeared which allows browsers to do DNS queries on their own, bypassing any shortcomings of the OS. SVCB allows to solve multiple problems at once: servers location for a given service (as in SRV) but also protocol signaling (alpn),"CNAME at apex" and help for ECH. Plus ipv4hint/ipv6hint to reduce number of queries. Browser vendors were also on board since the beginning of specifications.Some didn't like the form of SRV records (with the underscore) which is "solved" by HTTPS records.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: this specification is now published as RFC 9460.