# Setup split DNS to external CNAME when resolving within an internal CoreDNS?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, cloudflare

I have an internally hosted DNS resolver via `Core DNS` running on my network. Everything is great aside from one thing, which is I cannot load my apex domain when connected over VPN. The reasoning is because the zonefile maps my domain name to the internal IP of NGINX which has a ton of subdomain entries for my domain.

- thing1.example.com <- works
- thing2.example.com <- works
- example.com <- does not work.

Specifically, I want to load this website from outside my network.

I thought I would have a CNAME entry in the Zone file that routes traffic, even on VPN to my site hosted externally by Cloudflare, but apparently I am now going beyond my knowledge. How can I achieve this and what is this type of thing called?

Here is my zone file

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
@   3600 IN SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. (
                2017042746 ; serial
                7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                )
* 3600 in A 172.16.0.2 # this is private static IP I assigned to NGINX on internal network 
example.com. 3600 IN CNAME proxy.example.com.
```

The A record is good. I just added this CNAME but it does a loop back into NGINX and loads the wrong site.

`proxy.example.com` is a *CNAME* record in Cloudflare DNS that points to example.com. Doesn't work when connecting over VPN though. Maybe someone with some solid networking knowledge can explain this one to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Comment: @EsaJokinen no as I'm still unsure how to resolve my situation which is to have external DNS resolution to a domain from internal DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your current attempt:

- You [cannot use a `CNAME` record at the apex of a domain](https://serverfault.com/q/613829/274176).
- Your `proxy.example.com.` is part of the `* IN A 172.16.0.2`.

What could work:

1. Add an internal **copy** of the `proxy.example.com. A`. It must be configured exactly as the corresponding record on global DNS hierarchy, and should be updated separately whenever the external copy is updated.
2. Add `example.com. IN A 172.16.0.2` pointing at your Nginx.
3. Configure the Nginx to perform a HTTP redirect from `http(s)://example.com/` to `http(s)://proxy.example.com/`.

Best practices:

- Do not use the same zone externally and internally.
- You could delegate a subdomain of your external domain for internal use.

  - E.g., `thing1.internal.example.com`

Comment: I'm still confused here. proxy.example.com is a site hosted by cloudflare. There isn't a single IP for this domain and it doesn't allow direct IP access. Am I missing something?

Comment: Additionally, I'm unsure how a 301 on nginx would work as DNS resolution would again, resolve to the internal IP.

Comment: Without the actual domain there are too many details unknown to us.

Comment: But in general: do not use split DNS. It creates more problems than it can solve.